# Integer and Decimal related

Tags: c

This is the part of my program I am stuck on. When I enter say 5.5 my program will run twice, however I want it to read as 5.5 not 5 then 5 again. I understand I need to add %f (hence added a float input), however, I'm not sure how I will implement it after I do a scanf for char. I only want the program to accept integer so it cannot accept 5.5 as a value. It is in a do-while loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated, please explain thoroughly because I am still kind of new to programming.

```
int amount;
float input;

do{
       printf("\nPlease enter integer:");          
       if(scanf("%d", &amount)!= 1){ 
       //if reads a character or symbol asks to try again
           printf("\nEnter numbers only!\n"); 
           getchar();
       }
```

...

Comment: If you only want integers then why are you typing 5.5 ? If you want to make it accept any input then you really need to read a string and convert the string to an int.

Comment: im putting in 5.5 to test but I only want it to accept integer. i need it to accept value between 5 and 95c (as integers) that is multiple of 5 ONLY, I've done everything else it is just this I'm not familiar with.. please if you can show me an example and explain

Comment: If someone enter 5.0 or 10.0, does it count as valid input?

Comment: for 10.0 it reads 10 as valid and 0 as invalid

Comment: it also reads the . as invalid

Answer (score 1):

Using `scanf` with an integer format (`%d`) and then feeding non integer values is a recipe for disaster (or at least your program not working).

Either use scanf and only type integers or read strings and convert the strings to integers.

```
do {
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t sz = 0;

    printf("\nPlease enter integer:");
    getline(&line, &sz, stdin);
    if (line == NULL) {
        // TODO error handling
        // Can also check the getline() -1 is an error.
    } else {    
        // atoi returns 0 on error, so if 0 is a valid value you'll
        // need special case handling to determine if you've got a 
        // "valid" 0 or not.
        amount = atoi(line);
        free(line);
    }
```